# How can I get the Rhythmbox visualization window back in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

I just chose to have the visualization in separate window once, now it looks like this:

[image]

I can't find a way to get it back in Rhythmbox. There are no buttons and no menu entries to move it back.

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hovering a mouse over the visualization, a window appears that allows the selection of the visualization mode.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Thats what I would expect - but in fact when i hover the mouse over the low window border, nothing like that happens! None of those 3 memues appears, only the mouse arrow change into the mode to change the window size. I can wait for minutes and search pixel for pixel....these menues are not reachable.